# how to Block a directory with .htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I want to block a directory.

Say, `www.mysite.com/folder/`

and also `www.mysite.com/folder/index.php`

When ever someone access that URL, it should show error 404.

I also want one file in that directory access able. e.g  `www.mysite.com/folder/page.php`

How could we do that with .htaccess or some other method?

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^folder(/(?!page\.php$).*|)$ - [R=404,L,NC]
```